# $[] is not updating the all array element?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Everyone I'm beginner in MongoDB.I have to update with certain condition like To increment all elements in the grades array by 10 for all documents except those with the value 100 in the grades array.Thanks in advance...Can anyone know how to solve this issue? I have collections like

```html
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c21f8cf410eff09884860b1"),
    "name" : "vignesh",
    "grades" : [ 
        85, 
        82, 
        80
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c21f8e9410eff09884860b5"),
    "name" : "vinoth",
    "grades" : [ 
        88, 
        90, 
        92
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c21f903410eff09884860bf"),
    "name" : "waseem",
    "grades" : [ 
        85, 
        100, 
        90
    ]
}
```

This is my code:

```html
 async function doarrayupdate(){

    const result=await GradeDetails.update({grades:{$ne:100}},{
        $inc:{
          "grades.$[]":10
        }
    },{multi:true});

    console.log(result._doc);

    }
    doarrayupdate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**`arrayFilters`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) here and with

> The positional [**`$[<identifier>]`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) operator which acts as a placeholder for all
>   elements in the array field that match the conditions specified in
>   arrayFilters.

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
   { },
   { "$inc": { "grades.$[element]" : 10 } },
   { "multi": true,
     "arrayFilters": [ { "element": { "$ne": 100 } } ]
   }
)
```

Comment: I have tried Array Filtering but  it shows "MongoError: Unrecognized field in update operation: arrayFilters"

Comment: If you are using mongodb 3.6 or above then it should definitely work

Comment: Thankyou I have changed to 4.0.2 version.Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
 GradeDetails.update({grades:{$nin:[100]}},{
    $inc:{
      "grades.$[]":10
    }
},{multi:true});
```

you have to use [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/#op._S_nin) for getting an array which is not containing a value.

Comment: This will not work as it only filters the documents not the nested array

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have tried this in the local mongo, this is working correctly, check this [output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3uv0ve9577cifqt/Screenshot%202018-12-25%2016.32.50.png?dl=0). Are you doing something like this?

Comment: See the `nMatched` and `nModified`. It should update all the documents i.e. `nMatched` should be `3` and `nModified` should also be `3` because all the documents contain the grades and only single element inside the grades is 100 which should be updated which the OP wants